# Android studio update (3.1.1) and now app won't run

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I updated my android studio this morning to 3.1.1 and went to change some code and run my app again but I keep getting errors and not sure how to fix it, I have searched on SO and with Google, but haven't seen anything that relates to this. I have also tried to clean and rebuild as well and still same errors when trying to build or run app.

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug' 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt 

Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: So you down vote without explaining anything? How does that help anyone?

Comment: Try turning off Instant Run    (1) Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.
   (2) Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
   (3) Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes. (4) Re-build.

Comment: @JonGoodwin TY so much, that let me launch my app again. Please make an answer below and I will accept it.

Comment: The task that is failing is `:app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug`, so worth a try. Deleting cache also worth a punt. Also check gradle plugin (classpath) `3.1.1` with gradle version `4.4`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The task that is failing is:
`:app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug`

Try turning off Instant Run:

1. Open the `Settings` or `Preferences` dialog: On `Windows` or `Linux`,
   select File > Settings from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select Android
   Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.
2. Navigate to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run`.
3. **Uncheck** the box next to Restart activity on code changes.
4. Re-build.

This is  [Google issue 72811718](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72811718) a bug in AS 3.1+

Comment: TY again, this was a very simple solution and worked without any additional steps.

Answer (score 0):

In the project-level build.gradle, changing

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

Fixed it for me