# Failed to find byte code for android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager$AuthenticationCallback

Tags: android

I get the following error while trying to run my app from Android Studio:

> Failed to find byte code for
>   android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager$AuthenticationCallback

Error occurred after updating `buildToolsVersion` to `'27.0.3'`.
Android `Gradle` plugin version `3.1.1`, `Gradle` version `4.4`.

How I can fix this?

Comment: If you don't want to revert Android Studio 3.1 to 3.0, you can disable Instant Run (it maybe [issue 72811718](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72811718)). See [my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888065/android-studio-update-and-now-app-wont-run/49888586#49888586) on how to do it.

Comment: Disabled Instant Run resolved issue. Thank you, you saved my day! :)

Comment: First of all welcome to StackOverflow. Your first day, your first question.
As a new user this site can be a bit intimidating.
(we have quite strict quality control, unlike other sites).
Be prepared for brutal analysis of your questions ! 
Please take a moment to see the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),(you get a badge for looking at it!).
**Your question is under threat of closure (x2) due to *"Questions seeking debugging help"*, please update it with more detail (logcat)).**
It's a mostly user monitored site so where people are involved, random things happen.

Comment: I had to be almost **clairvoyant** to see what your problem was, luckily my last answer was the so similar I thought it might help you. Remember to vote (**a lot**) on things you like or dislike, it's important for **quality control** on **this** site.
If you have a complaint, refer it to the moderators (**flag**).
If you want to message some one use the **@** symbol and their username (I am @Jon Goodwin).
Mark question as **Answered** if it have been Answered to your satisfaction.
**Enjoy StackOverflow**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah the instant run bug raises it's head again.

To disable Instant Run just uncheck the tick box ([see SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888065/android-studio-update-and-now-app-wont-run/49888586#49888586)).

This is  [Google issue 72811718](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72811718) a bug in AS 3.1+

Answer (score 0):

FingerprintManager is now deprecated. API 28 BiometricPrompt is used so for now ! but it only works on Android Studio 3.2 which is currently not available. but soon it'll be...

Answer (score 0):

You should first check whether the `Permission` `android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT` is included in the `Manifest` or not. If not should be included and built.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the Instant Run option on Android studio